# Maven pipeline fails to find JDK

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a problem running a simple Java Maven pipeline. The used maven command fails using the expected JDK for an unknown reason.

- freshly installed Jenkins running from the docker image jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
- configured Oracle JDK 9 and Maven 3.5.4 at the Jenkins Tools settings pane

Jenkinsfile content:

```
    pipeline {
      agent any
      tools {
        jdk 'java9'
        maven 'Maven3.5'
      }
      stages {
        stage ('Initialize') {
          steps {
            sh '''
              echo "PATH = ${PATH}"
              echo "M2_HOME = ${M2_HOME}"
              echo "JAVA_HOME = ${JAVA_HOME}"
            '''
          }
        }
        stage ('Build') {
          steps {
            sh 'java -version'
            sh 'mvn --version'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Output of the "Initialize" stage script

```
PATH = /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/java9/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven3.5/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/java9/bin:/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven3.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin

M2_HOME = /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven3.5

JAVA_HOME = /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/java9
```

This looks valid to me. M2_HOME and JAVA_HOME point to the expected path of the Jenkins tools.

Output of the "Build" "java -version" script

```
+ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.10.0) (Alpine 8.191.12-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

This seems to be the installed Java of the Jenkins docker host system

Failure output of the "Build" "mvn -version" script:

```
mvn --version
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven3.5/bin/mvn: exec: line 191: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/java9/bin/java: not found
script returned exit code 127
```

If I bash into the Jenkins docker container, I find the java bin at the mentioned path.

Where is my mistake? Why can't Maven find the Java?

Is it a permission problem? Jenkins docker container uses a docker volume:
`-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home`.

Best,
Lars

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when you're using an alpine based docker image for jenkins and your jdk is glibc based. You can solve this in two ways:

1. Use a jdk that is musl based. You can find them on adoptium by filtering out the OS as Alpine Linux.
2. Use a non-alpine based docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure tools + docker in Jenkins Pipeline is working so good.

See: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36159

Only way so far I've managed to get this to work was by mounting the docker node's tools directory into the docker slave.

e.g.

agent { docker 
args '-v $HOME/tools:/var/lib/jenkins/tools'

stage { step {
sh "${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/mvn -version"

EDIT: Just found this too: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48050

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both tools. It is enough with Maven tool. It includes Java. Your pipeline should be:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    maven 'Maven3.5'
  }
  stages {
    stage ('Initialize') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          echo "PATH = ${PATH}"
          echo "M2_HOME = ${M2_HOME}"
          echo "JAVA_HOME = ${JAVA_HOME}"
        '''
      }
    }
    stage ('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'java -version'
        sh 'mvn --version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you can delete Java Tool in Jenkins configuration tool.